# Turn php error reporting off in xampp?

Tags: php

I just installed xampp, getting errors all over the place. Want to get rid of error handling. It's only annoying errors to do with my variables.

I'm not sure where to find php.ini, it doesn't exist in my `C:\xampp\apache`

Comment: `php_info()` will show you the right location of php.ini.

Comment: Call to undefined function php_echo()

Comment: The best way to get rid of error messages is to _fix your bugs_. Turning off error reporting is pretty much the worst idea you could have.

Comment: I realize it's a bad idea, but it's my choice. I want them off. I'm porting an ancient script to another server and I'm not about to sift through the filth of another coder for hundreds of hours because he was incompetent. The code works and I just need to have the errors off to have it function properly.

Also, I changed the values in php.ini, restarted apache but the values do not take effect.

Comment: with errors it shouldn't work, perhaps you meant notices.

Comment: "Ancient script"? Are you sure you're not just gettint E_STRICT | E_DEPRECATED errors? I exclude fatal errors as the script works, so there could be notices...which should be fixed anyway. Not fixing errors is being as incompetent (as you say) as making them. But I'm pretty sure turning error reporting to E_ALL & ~ E_STRICT would be enough

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Inside your `php.ini` make sure that you have `display_errors` to Off. From what I understand if you set display_errors to Off then the error_reporting directive doesn't need to change.

Example:

```
error_reporting = E_COMPILE_ERROR|E_ERROR|E_CORE_ERROR
display_errors = Off
```

Answer (score 3):

This is very old now, but in case someone comes across this there's a XAMMP issue with version 5.6.3.  I had the same issue with error display set to 'off' and it was still showing up as on in phpinfo()

For some reason, they added the error reporting in php.ini twice. *display_errors* shows on line 99 of php.ini, and then again on line 552.

So if you scroll down and disable the first one, the second one is still set to 'on' and overrides the first one leaving error reporting active.

I'm sure this will be fixed with future versions of XAMMP, but wanted to add this here for anyone that comes here looking for an answer to this problem.

Comment: This has been eating my head all day.. I wish I could give more upvotes

Answer (score 2):

in php.ini, do the following change,

```
display_errors = Off
```

Comment: Do you realize how old this question is? There's already a correct answer. Don't bump year old questions!

Answer (score 1):

If you set display_errors=off then all types of error will of.

But if you only want to notice error off the you can set
`error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE`

Answer (score 1):

Xampp and other web applications have an error interface to show programmers (and users) execution errors or warnings (notices).
In order to modify the way Xampp shows errors you have to go control panel and open php.ini.
Inside this file you can find two points to modify the way it shows errors:

1. “display_errors = On”. From my point of view it has to be On all the time. If you put Off you won’t have any info regarding bad sentences.
2. “error_reporting=E_ALL”. This is the key point. Changing the value of it you can change the way it shows errors. 
   Inside php.ini is documented all options. My favorites:

   - error_reporting=E_ALL  it shows everything. Good for debug.
   - error_reporting=E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED  it shows errors & notice (very important for debugging) and not shows suggestions & deprecated functions in next php versions.
   - error_reporting=E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED  production environment not including Notices.

I hope this fit for you.

More details https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=50989